# How to override a type of a package globally?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to override this type that [being used in Zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/blob/d2ac69c08fe122b85955bd3c292b5e62c08ed598/src/types.ts#L70) with a custom enum. This is the type exported by Zod:

```js
export type CustomErrorParams = Partial<util.Omit<ZodCustomIssue, "code">>;
```

I have this declarations to be used globally, but Typescript is not overriding it for me right now. I can confirm that this `global.d.ts` file is being loaded correctly by my framework.

```js
import type { InvalidCode } from '$lib/types'

declare module "zod" {
    export type CustomErrorParams = InvalidCode
}
```

How can I override that?